# Why does thunderbird move the style of the html header?

Tags: html, css, html-email, thunderbird, html-templates

I am creating responsive email templates, I use Thunderbird to send some tests.

In most email clients it works very well. However in Gmail the styles are not applied.

Checking the CSS support I found that gmail only supports <style> inside the <head> tag. [MailChimp](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/)

[Css Support in gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        .colored {
          color:red;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>
        This text is blue if the window width is
        below 500px and red otherwise.
      </p>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Knowing this, I implanted my styles inside the head, however, the styles were not applied in GMAIL.

After researching on various forums and breaking my head I couldn't find the solution, so I checked the obvious, it turns out that **Thunderbird moves the <style> from <head> to <body>**

When I send the template through Thunderbird and see the source of the mail, I get this:
[image: Link]

---

```html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/78.7.1

<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class="colored"> This text is blue if the window width is below
        500px and red otherwise. </p>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        .colored {
          color:red;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

When I send the template through mailutils, the behavior is as expected and the styles work correctly in gmail

[image: Link]

---

```html
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 3.7)

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        .colored {
          color:red;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>
        This text is blue if the window width is
        below 500px and red otherwise.
      </p>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

View of gmail:
[image: Link]

---

**How to prevent thunderbird from moving the style to the body?**
I am using Thunderbird 78.7.1, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: I would suggest using an email service like mailchimp to send your emails. Its free for limited number of contacts. Thunderbird is an email client. If you send an email from MailChimp and open in thunderbird, you will see it renders very similar to Gmail.

Comment: Most email clients rewrite emails when they send or receive. They strip out tags the client does not support. Others like Gmail rewrite the entire email. I would go with advice from  @Syfer with one caveat. MailChimp does not support custom templates and also rewrites  HTML code. I would suggest another provider.

Comment: @gwally Re MailChimp, what you said could imply you can't use custom templates at all. So, they let you use custom templates, but they don't help you fix your code if that's the way you go.

Comment: @Nathan I appreciate the clarification. Yes, you can use custom templates on MailChimp, but they modify your template and offer no technical support if you run into an issue.

Comment: If you can't use an actual ESP to send your tests, try a service like [useparcel.com](https://useparcel.com).

Note: ironically, Thunderbird has recently dropped support for `@media` queries, so HTML emails are no longer responsive in it right now (see [caniemail.com](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-media/))

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I fixed it by simply downloading the plugin [ThunderHTMLedit](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/thunderhtmledit/) and it works as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this strange behavior occurs when the HTML code is **inserted** from the **thunderbird options**
[image]

---

To avoid this behavior you must use the plugin [ThunderHTMLedit](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/thunderhtmledit/) and insert the HTML template from the **HTML** tab when composing the email
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an add-on, CustomCSS, for Thunderbird that adds CSS to the `<head>`.
I have personally tried it and it works :)
There are two downsides to the add-on.
a) It applies to all email accounts, cannot customize per account.
b) The editor is very basic (cannot use a CSS file).
Link to the add-on:
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/customcss/
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NUXn.png)